# Automatically Invoke a jQuery Plugin on a Dynamically-Created Element

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling

I need to apply a jQuery plugin to an HTML element that will be created upon a user's input. For example:

```
<!-- Upon click, this link creates a new div with an id of 'target'. -->
<a id="trigger-a" href="javascript:void(0);">Create a new div</a>

/* This will not work because div#target isn't available yet upon page load. */
$(function() {
  $("div#target").aJQueryPlugin( ... );
});
```

In the simplest form, I can call the plugin inside the `<a>`'s click handler, after the div is created.

```
$(function() {
  $("#trigger-a").click(function() {
    // Create div#target.

    // I can call the plugin here but is there a different, maybe better, way?
    $("div#target").aJQueryPlugin( ... );
  });
});
```

However, if possible, I am looking for something that is more "automatic"; maybe using `.on()` that automatically invokes the plugin once the element becomes available?

**Paraphrasing the question:**
In jQuery, is there a way to "monitor" when a certain element becomes available (i.e. after it's being created)? If there is, I'd then call the plugin or other functions as a callback.

Comment: Can you explain why running the plugin in the same function as you're creating the div is not a viable option, it seems to me to be most efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

### HTML

```
<a id="trigger-a" href="javascript:void(0);">Create a new div</a>

<div class="cont"></div>
```

### JS

```
$("#trigger-a").click(function () {
    var $div = $('<div>', {class: 'target', text: 'text'});
    $('.cont').append($div);
    $div.trigger('divCreate');
});

$('.cont').on('divCreate', 'div.target', function () {
    $(this).append('added by event')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2UYC/

Triggering custom event let you bind event handler later.

Comment: Isn't that the same as just running the plugin in the same function as the div is created.

Comment: Well, it's similiar, but you trigger event once in one place, then u can bind multiple events handler later.

Comment: This doesn't exactly provide the solution for the question presented. However, it suggests an interesting alternative: trigger a custom event using `trigger()`. Thus, in the interest of time, this was chosen as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'DOMNodeInserted' which is not a jQuery event.

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {

//write your stuff here to check if desired element was inserted or not.

    alert('inserted ' + event.target.nodeName + // new node
        ' in ' + event.relatedNode.nodeName); // parent
});
```

Comment: `bind()` has been deprecated and replaced with `on()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you must check the element is there before calling the plugin, you could probably try something like this:

```
$('#click-here').click(function() {
    $(this).after('<button class="new-button">I am a new button</button>');

    var checkElement = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('.new-button').length) {
            $('.new-button').button({'label': 'I am a new fancy button'});
            clearInterval(checkElement);
        }
    }, 200);
});
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jreyes33/KDhQ5/1/).

Note that the `.button` function is a jQuery UI plugin initialization, so it should also work for the plugin you need. You should also change the setInterval second argument to something else, 200 is just to show a delay.

Comment: Hhmm... this actually has exactly the same step as my code in the question. What I am trying to solve is how *not* to call the plugin inside the `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `delegate` and `on` are both good for this. Note that if you use older versions of jQuery you can use `delegate` but if you use the latest version (1.7+) you need to use `on`.

With these you must call the method using an element that is already loaded and use a parameter to specify to element that fires the event. To make this as efficient as possible this element should be the closest parent to the dynamically created element.

For instance if on click of the anchor tag, you place a div with id of 'target' into a container that was already loaded before the call to `on`, with an id of 'container', your `on` call should be.

```
$('#container').on('click', '#target', function(){ $(this).pluginCall(); });
```

You cant simply just call `on` onto the #target div because that element has not been loaded yet.

The other solution is to place a `$(document).ready()` function inline into your dynamically created content that calls your plugin. You wont need `on` or `delegate` in this instance but this will only work for the currently loaded elements. In the first example, any instance of #target that gets created from any ajax call will be the `click` handler.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @andbeyond. `$('#container').on('click', '#target', function() { $(this).pluginCall(); });` actually requires `#target` to be clicked before the plugin fires. I want the plugin to fire *immediately* after the new `<div>` is created, *without* requiring a new event to happen.

Comment: Ok, so in this case you should call the plugin oncomplete of the AJAX request or after the content is placed on the DOM

Comment: This goes back to the original question: how to trigger the plugin after the element is available *without* doing it directly inside the `<a>` click handler?

Comment: You clearly have some function that fires on click of the anchor which places a new div onto the DOM, so right before that function returns you simply add the line that calls your plugin

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com, let's see the code that dynamically creates the new element.

Answer (score 0):

I would also be interested to see the code that inserts the new DOM object. Let's assume it's something like this: (you really shouldn't be using `onclick` handlers)

```
$("#trigger-a").click(function() {
    $(this).after('<div id="someDiv"></div>');

    $that = $("#someDiv");

    $that.ajQueryPlugin(...);
});
```

Is the best I can do without seeing more information...

Click the trigger, insert the new div, grab that object and run the plugin on it. Basically you're operating on the div **at the time of creation**, no need to 'monitor'.

Comment: I was actually looking for a possible way to *monitor* as originally stated in the question.

Comment: Why would you need to _monitor_ if **you're** the one creating the DOM element. Just execute the plugin when you create the DOM element...unless you have some mechanism for users to inject Javascript into your page, this should be all you need to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't bring the plugin in at the same time as the element creation (like [andbeyond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784855/andbeyond) suggested in their comment), for whatever reason, my advice would be to use Brandon Aaron's LiveQuery plugin:

http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

> ...Live Query also has the ability to fire a function (callback) when it matches a new element and another function (callback) for when an element is no longer matched. This provides ultimate flexibility and untold use-cases.

Hope that's helpful :)

Comment: jQuery built-in `.on()` method already takes care of what this plugin is supposed to cover.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `live()` or `on()` for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#target').on('click',function(){});
});
```